# How to round to exactly N digits after the decimal in Python?

Tags: python, rounding

Is there a way to actually round a number, any number to N digits after the decimal?
Like, the number 8 and N = 3 then it should be like 8.000
Or 6.9 and N = 3, it should be 6.900
Sorry if it should have been obvious, I'm a beginner.

i used the:
`round(num,N)`
function but for whole numbers and numbers that have less than N decimal digits, it didn't do anything. Can anyone help me?

Comment: The number 8 is the number 8, no matter how many 0 after the decimal point. What you are looking for is not "rounding" the number, but "formatting how the number is displayed". e,g, ``print(f"{8:.3f}")`` will output ``8.000``

Comment: The round function will round the number. You want to print it with N digits after the decimal you should just use `print(f'{x:.3f}')` with x = 8, it will print `8.000`.

Comment: If you are NOT just considering how it is output (which is merely a formatting issue, as already addressed by comments) then you would need to store it as the corresponding (possibly large) integer. For example, if N=3, then store THOUSANDTHS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python, the `round()` function will not add trailing zeros. If you want to format a number to have a specific number of digits after the decimal point, you can use string formatting. Here's how you can do it:

```
num = 8
N = 3
formatted_num = f"{num:.{N}f}"
print(formatted_num)  # Outputs: 8.000
```

In this code, `f"{num:.{N}f}"` is a formatted string literal (also known as f-string). The `{num:.{N}f}` inside the f-string is a placeholder that gets replaced with the value of `num`, formatted as a floating-point number with `N` digits after the decimal point. The `f` at the end of the placeholder stands for "float", and the `.` before it is used to specify the precision (the number of digits after the decimal point).

Answer (score -1):

use `round` function

```
number = 3.141592653589793
N = 3  # Number of digits after the decimal point

rounded_number = round(number, N)
print(rounded_number)  # Output: 3.142
```

Comment: But if the number is `9.0001` the op wants the output to be `9.000` not `9` (which is what your answer would do).